# A quick string checksum function in Perl generating values in the 0..2^32-1 range

Tags: perl, string, checksum, cpan, hashcode

I'm looking for a Perl string checksum function with the following properties:

- Input: Unicode string of undefined length (`$string`)
- Output: Unsigned integer (`$hash`), for which `0 <= $hash <= 2^32-1` holds (0 to 4294967295, matching the size of a 4-byte MySQL unsigned int)

Pseudo-code:

```
sub checksum {
    my $string = shift;
    my $hash;
    ... checksum logic goes here ...
    die unless ($hash >= 0);
    die unless ($hash <= 4_294_967_295);
    return $hash;
}
```

Ideally the checksum function should be quick to run and should generate values somewhat uniformly in the target space (`0` .. `2^32-1`) to avoid collisions. In this application random collisions are totally non-fatal, but obviously I want to avoid them to the extent that it is possible.

**Given these requirements, what is the best way to solve this?**

Comment: You want to avoid collisions with all possible strings, but only have a 4 billion possible digests? Why is using an integer important? How about just using something like MD5, even if you have to store the digest as a string?

Comment: "You want to avoid collisions with all possible strings" - No, as stated in the question I simply "want to avoid them to the extent that it is possible".

Comment: "Why is using an integer important?" - As stated in the question the the checksum will be stored in "a 4-byte MySQL unsigned int".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any hash function will be sufficient - simply truncate it to 4-bytes and convert to a number. Good hash functions have a random distribution, and this distribution will be constant no matter where you truncate the string.

I suggest [Digest::MD5](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Digest-MD5/MD5.pm) because it is the fastest hash implementation that comes with Perl as standard. String::CRC, as Pim mentions, is also implemented in C and should be faster.

Here's how to calculate the hash and convert it to an integer:

```
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5);
my $str = substr( md5("String-to-hash"), 0, 4 );
print unpack('L', $str);  # Convert to 4-byte integer (long)
```

Comment: B::hash also comes with core perl, uses the internal core hash function, is faster than MD5 and returns an hexified 32-bit integer. But not as secure as MD5.

Answer (score 5):

From `perldoc -f unpack`:

```
        For example, the following computes the same number as the
        System V sum program:

            $checksum = do {
                local $/;  # slurp!
                unpack("%32W*",<>) % 65535;
            };
```

Comment: This 32bit sums of all bits is a very bad hash value for random distributions. Any hash function is better, even the most simple ones.

Comment: Sure, but that's the same problem that the System V `sum` program has.  See the paragraph.  Or are you arguing that `sum` is arguably broken? In that case, it's not about Perl.

Comment: `sum` is about as quick as you'll get, though as noted above, it isn't terribly robust. You can improve it slightly by using the size, e.g. `$_ = <>; unpack("%32W*",$_)%65535 . length($_)`. Anything that needs to be more robust should use `Digest::MD5` or `Digest::SHA`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know how quick it is, but you might try [String::CRC](http://search.cpan.org/dist/String-CRC).